# Resize DropDownMenu

Tags: swift

I'm new in iOS development. 
I use this library (
https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu ) in order to create **DropDownMenu** to the navigation bar title view. But the problem is that the title is too long and i can't resize the TitleView.
Here is My code and don't work.

```
let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(navigationController: self.navigationController, title: self.clausenames.first!, items: self.clausenames)
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44))
v.addSubview(menuView)
self.navigationItem.titleView = v
```

help me please!

Answer (score 0):

**BTNavigationDropdownMenu** is a library full of `private` vars.

To change label size (number of lines, width..) you can be meet serious difficulties because the resources are protected and even making extensions to modify his resources throught by checking subviews objects by the kind of classes you must be careful from state of hide/show menu.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me the best way to use dropDownMenu?

Comment: Have you follow the demo examples in the official github repo? There there are the best ways to use this lib..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will follow it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(navigationController: self.navigationController, title: self.clausenames.first!, items: self.clausenames)
self.navigationItem.titleView = menuView
```